# Android KeyguradManager, KeyguradLock.disableKeyguard() Invalid

Tags: android

I want to disable the system lock screen.
the code is invalid as below:

```
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKeyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock("KeyguardLock");
    if (km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
        mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
    }
```

who can tell me why and how to do it? thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "the code is invalid"? What are you trying to accomplish? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you call is deprecated in API level 13,you should use `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` and/or `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` instead,for detail document  [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html)